# vba excel sheets.range.value Error

Tags: vba, excel

So, sometimes when I try to execute this command, it gives me an error. The problem is that it is very inconsistent. In certain cases, it works and in others, it just doesn't.

This is the line from getCellVal function. cellName is a string and s is an integer.

```
getCellVal = Sheets(s).Range(cellName).Value
```

This time it is giving me:
Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method

This line actually worked without problems moments ago. I added some other functions that use it and now it's not working anymore.

Any ideas about why?

Comment: If `cellName` is a `Named Range` with workbook scope, then remove the `Sheets(s).` from the right side.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld unqualified `Range` calls implicitly refer to the active worksheet (unless you're in a worksheet's code-behind) - that would actually make things *worse* ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Not so if it is a `Defined Name` with Workbook Scope, which is what I wrote.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Fine. But then that would be error 1004, not 438.

Comment: FWIW accessing defined names should be done via the `Workbook.Names` collection for workbook-scoped names, and via the `Worksheet.Names` collection for worksheet-scoped names. `Range`'s behavior is broken and unintuitive.

Comment: @Mat'sMug That would depend on the type of sheet and which sheet.  If it is the same worksheet, then it will work; if it happens to be a Chart sheet, then the `438`, and if it is a different worksheet, then `1004`.  If it is a `Named Range` with workbook scope, and you eliminate the `Sheets` argument, then no errors no matter the active sheet.  Obviously, if it is a cell address, then you need a valid sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unqualified calls into the `Sheets` collection implicitly refer to whatever workbook is currently active, and it's important to know that the collection contains `Worksheet` objects, ...but also `Chart` objects.

Since you mean to work with a `Worksheet`, use the `Worksheets` collection instead.

If you're not getting an "index out of bounds" error, then the sheet you asked for does exist. But error 438 points to that sheet not being a `Worksheet` (and thus not having a `Range` member).

I bet the active workbook has a chart sheet at index `s`.

The solution is simply to be explicit.

If you mean to work with the workbook that contains the code that's running, qualify `Workbook` member calls with `ThisWorkbook`:

```
getCellVal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(s).Range(cellName).Value
```

If you mean to work with *a* workbook, then you need to get ahold of the `Workbook` object when you open it:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(path)
'...
getCellVal = wb.Worksheets(s).Range(cellName).Value
```